# Logic app with high availability reading from service bus topic

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-topics

We have a logic app running in high availability mode reading from a message queue. Having it read from a message queue ensured that only one of the logic app instances could process it.  Now we need to change the queue to a topic which, if I understand it correctly, means we lost our ability to ensure that only one instance of the logic app processes the message.  So my question is there a way to have a logic app be enabled for high availability, read from a topic, and ensure that only one instance processes a given message as it arrives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Logic App to process message from a particular Subscription under a Topic.

There is nothing different between listening for messages from a Queue and Topic Subscription. Only one instance processes the message as the message will be locked when it is received, so there can be only one active listener.

Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-servicebus) for listening messages from Topic Subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

**TL/DR:** Peek/Lock works the same weather the message arrives via a Topic or directly from a Queue.